# Cannot reinstall Windows 10 on tablet

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, windows-installation

And by reinstall, I mean plug in a USB drive and run the installer from there. (i had deleted all partitions except EFI to make space to install Android which ultimately failed) Because when i try to install Windows on the 28.9GB NTFS partition i had just created with GPT, it says that it 'does not contain the sufficient space to install Windows.'

How do I fix this problem and install it?

Comment: Delete all the partitions, boot to installation media, and install Windows 10

Comment: Okay, so does that include deleting the EFI partition too? @Ramhound

Comment: My first comment is clear, you should delete, all the partitions on the disk.